# itext repaint borders of a table

Tags: border, itext, pdfptable

I write a pdfptable to a document and than I add an header table and a footer table using onStartPage events.

My problem is that if the main table has a top border this will partially overwritten by the header. The naive solution is to write the header onStartPage, but than I have the same problem with a bottom border in the header.

My idea was to rewrite the borders of all tables onEndPage, but it think this is not easy. 
A solution would be to insert header and main table as nested table to another table, but this is not practicable in my case.

Any suggestions/experience in this area?

Comment: Have you tried using cell events?

Comment: I dont' see how... I have to repaint the borders onEndPage (after all the tables within the page have been written)

Comment: You don't see how cell or table events would help. I don't see how anyone can answer your question in its current state. Please rephrase it because "I have to repaint the borders `onEndPage`" sounds wrong, functionally as well as grammatically.

Comment: I'm regretful for my bad explanation, I have rewritten the question and I hope it is now clearer

Comment: First of all, *don't add content to a document during `onStartPage`, move the code to `onEndPage` instead* because adding content during `onStartPage` (while it may seem to work at first) eventually will result in surprising effects. That been said your target seems to be adding table headers and footers into the page headers and footers. What about reducing the top and bottom margin of the pages in question and using PdfPTable header and footer rows instead?